# How can I get a package update in the repositories?

Tags: package-management, repository, deb, debian, anki

I use a software ([Anki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki)) which is in version 0.9.9.8.6-2.1 in the [Debian repository](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/anki) and in version 1.2.11-1 in the [Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/anki). Quite a lot has changed meanwhile ([changelog](http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Anki-Changelog-26489.html)). The latest version is 2.0.8. Source code and a Debian package is already available (see [downloads](http://www.ankisrs.net/anki2.html#download)), but it is not in the repository.

Question 1: Where or who can I ask to update this package?

Question 2: When it gets updated in the Debian repository, will it automatically get updated in the Ubuntu repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know who is maintening the package, have a look... into the package :-)

In a terminal, type `apt-cache show anki`.
You'll get a lot of information, but the relevant lines are:

> Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
>   Original-Maintainer: Andreas Bombe

So, now you know the mainteners of the packages. To ask them to update their package, report a bug: in launchpad.net for Ubuntu, or http://www.debian.org/Bugs/ for debian.

So now, question #2: will update in Debian result in update in Ubuntu ? Well, it depends on when it happens. On each release cycle, Ubuntu is synced with Debian. This is done until a date known as https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebianImportFreeze. So if the update happens before this date, it will likely get into Ubuntu. Else, you'll have to wait for the next release cycle.

Comment: I've just found this "bug" in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anki/+bug/1066487). I also found a [needs packaging list](http://reqorts.qa.ubuntu.com/reports/needs-packaging/needs-packaging-popularity.html) on Launchpad.